# Find the smallest k such that $n^k > \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i^k$

Tags: number-theory, inequality, summation, exponentiation, exponential-function

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Is it possible to find the smallest $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$n^k > \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i^k \ ?$$

---

It's easy to prove that such $k$ exist because:

$$n^k > 1^k + 2^k + 3^k + 4^k + \dots + (n-2)^k + (n-1)^k$$
$$ \iff 1 > \left(\frac 1n\right)^k + \left(\frac 2n\right)^k + \left(\frac 3n\right)^k + \dots + \left(\frac {n-1}n\right)^k$$

And since all fractions tends to zero when $k \to \infty$, there must be a solution for $k$.

I've tried using logartihms, but I wasn't able to do anythyng.

Then I tried to find the value of the sum using [Faulhaber formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula), but the Faulhaber formula depends on the exponent $k$ and since it's not fixed it's almost useless.

Any other way to solve this?

Comment: I reworded your question slightly for clarity.  Please check it to make sure I have not interpreted your question incorrectly. Cheers!

Comment: Please forgive me if I'm doing something incorrect. I just wanted to ask why is the Faulhaber formula useless? $$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i^k ={1 \over k+1} \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j{k+1 \choose j} B_j (n-1)^{k+1-j},\qquad \mbox{where}~B_1 = -\frac{1}{2}$$ When a change of variables is made, the Faulhaber formula does not neccessarily depend on the exponent $k$.

Comment: @MatthewConroy It's all right.

Comment: Alert! The number of fractions also tends to $\infty$ ! You cannot use limit arithmetic here.

Comment: As I said we don't know what's the value of $k$, so how we will know when to stop in $\sum_{j=0}^k$ summation?

Comment: @Dror Yes you are right. But I think that such $k$ always exist

Comment: I thought the idea is that, for a fixed $n$, find the minimal $k$ such that the inequality is satisfied.  Hence, the number of terms does not tend to infinity: it is fixed to $n$.  For instance, with $n=10$, the inequality is satisfied for $k>5.8915157183...$, so $k=6$ would be the minimal integer $k$.

Comment: @MatthewConroy Yes $n$ is fixed, $n$ can be any natural number.

Comment: @MatthewConroy of course $n$ is fixed. What I meant to say was that the proof of existence in the body of the question is not so valid

Comment: @Dror Why? $k \to \infty$, not $n$

Comment: @Dror Can you elaborate? Your one complaint was that the number of fractions tends to infinity.  It does not.  So what is your complaint now?

Comment: There is none. I was confused. Don't shout.

Comment: @Dror Nobody is shouting.  Cheers!

Comment: You have proved that for every $n$, such $k$ must exist(but as $n$ gets larger, so does $k$). Do you want an exact integer value for the smallest $k$?

Comment: @chubakueno Yes, that's my question is there any way to find it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the inequality
$$
e^{-x/(1-x/k)}\le\left(1-\frac xk\right)^k\le e^{-x}\tag{1}
$$
and setting $x=\frac{ik}{n}$ we get
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{n^k}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i^k
&=\frac1{n^k}\sum_{i=1}^n(n-i)^k\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(1-\frac in\right)^k\\
&\le\sum_{i=1}^ne^{-ik/n}\\
&\le\frac1{e^{k/n}-1}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $k=\log(2)n$ is an upper bound.

Assuming $k/n$ is near $\log(2)$, we have for any $\alpha\gt0$,
$$
\begin{align}
\hspace{-1cm}\frac1{n^k}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i^k
&=\frac1{n^k}\sum_{i=1}^n(n-i)^k\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(1-\frac in\right)^k\\
&\ge\sum_{i=1}^ne^{-ik/(n-i)}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^ne^{-ik/n}-\sum_{i=1}^ne^{-ik/n}\left(1-e^{-i^2k/n/(n-i)}\right)\\
&\ge\color{#00A000}{\sum_{i=1}^ne^{-ik/n}}\color{#C00000}{-\sum_{i=1}^ne^{-ik/n}\frac{i^2k}{n(n-i)}}\\
&\ge\color{#00A000}{\sum_{i=1}^\infty e^{-ik/n}}\color{#C00000}{-\frac1{1-\alpha}\sum_{i=1}^{\alpha n}e^{-ik/n}\frac{i^2k}{n^2}-\sum_{i=\alpha n+1}^ne^{-ik/n}\frac{i^2k}{n}}\color{#00A000}{-\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty e^{-ik/n}}\\
&\ge\frac1{e^{k/n}-1}-\frac1{1-\alpha}\frac{k}{n^2}\frac{e^{-k/n}+e^{-2k/n}}{(1-e^{-k/n})^3}\color{#0000FF}{-e^{-\alpha k}\frac{nk}{e^{k/n}-1}-\frac{e^{-n}}{e^{k/n}-1}}\\
&\sim\frac1{e^{k/n}-1}-\frac{6\log(2)}{(1-\alpha)n}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
because the blue terms decay exponentially.

Since the derivative of $\frac1{e^x-1}$ at $x=\log(2)$ is $-2$, we get $\frac1{e^{k/n}-1}-\frac{6\log(2)}{n}=1$ at approximately $k=\log(2)(n-3)$. With a bit more care, we see that more precisely:
$$
k=\log(2)(n-3)-\frac{3\log(2)(17\log(2)-6)}{2n}+\dots\tag{4}
$$
Therefore, $k=\log(2)(n-3)$ is a good estimate for the lower bound.

---

**Proof of the Inequality**

Since $1+x\le e^x$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we have
$$
1-\frac xk\le e^{-x/k}\le\frac1{1+\frac xk}=1-\frac{x}{k+x}\tag{5}
$$
Therefore,
$$
e^{-x/(k-x)}\le1-\frac xk\le e^{-x/k}\tag{6}
$$
Raising to the $k^\text{th}$ power,
$$
e^{-x/(1-x/k)}\le\left(1-\frac xk\right)^k\le e^{-x}\tag{7}
$$
as desired.

Comment: And I actually proved with $k=n\log 2$ the identity in the OP question holds.

Comment: @127.0.9.6 proved that $k>2n/3-1$ is a necessary condition in order that the identity holds, we just need to fill the little gap between $\frac{2}{3}$ and $\log 2$.

Comment: @127.0.9.6: sorry, I hadn't read the other answers. I have now gotten bounds between $\log(2)n$ and $\log(2)(n-3)$ for large enough $n$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: yeah, I answered too quickly and then had to leave. Using a better estimate of $\left(1-\frac in\right)^k$, I have gotten a more reasonable result.

Comment: I understand the first downvote from my previous inadequate answer, but I am curious about the second downvote that appeared on my reworked answer.

Comment: @robjohn: the first downvote was mine, but I removed it since your answer is now perfectly ok, and fills the gap between $\frac{2}{3}$ and $\log 2$, too.

Comment: @robjohn First of all a brilliant answer, but can you show how does you find the lower bound from the derivative?

Comment: @Stefan4024: I have added a bit more about that.

Comment: @robjohn I understand that we need to set the last line to 1, but how do we find $k = \log(2)(n-3)$? And for the sum did you use some series? (ex. Taylor series?)

Comment: @Stefan4024: we know that $k/n$ is close to $\log(2)$. If we subtract things and drop the exponentially decaying terms, we get $$\frac1{e^{k/n}-1}=1+\frac{k/n}{n}\frac{e^{-k/n}+e^{-2k/n}}{(1-e^{-k/n})^3}$$ The right side is approximately $1+\frac{6\log(2)}{n}$.  Since the derivative of $\frac1{e^x-1}$ at $x=\log(2)$ is $-2$, the left side is approximately $1-2(k/n-\log(2))$. Equating the two sides yields $$\frac kn=\log(2)-\frac{3\log(2)}{n}$$ For more accuracy, we can carry this out to higher order.

Answer (score 10):

*Note: This post contains only  numerics; see the answers by robjohn and Jack D'Aurizio for actual math.*

Numerical computations show that 
$$k(n) = \lfloor n\log 2-0.039721\rfloor \quad \text{ for } \ 2\le n<944029$$
which is kind of nice. However, this empirical formula breaks down for $n=944029$. What is worse, it turns out there is no $c$ such that $k(n) = \lfloor n\log 2-c\rfloor$ holds for all $n$. Indeed, we have 
$$k(944029) = 654351, \quad \text{with } 944029\log(2)-654351 < 0.039717$$
$$k(603162) = 418079, \quad \text{with } \ 603162 \log 2 - 418079 > 1.0397208$$
So, the range of values of $n\log 2-k(n)$ exceeds $1$, if only by a tiny bit.

Still, it is reasonable to conjecture that $$\lfloor n\log 2\rfloor-1 \le k(n) \le \lfloor n\log 2\rfloor  \tag{??}$$ for all $n\ge 2$.

The upper bound was proved by Jack D'Aurizio and by robjohn; also, robjohn gave a lower bound that is very close to (??).

Answer (score 5):

Borrowing @Jason's notation for:
$$S_n(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^x$$
we have that:
$$S_n(x)=-1+(1+1/n)^x\cdot S_{n+1}(x)\leq -1+e^{x/n}\cdot S_{n+1}(x),\tag{1}$$
so in order to have $S_n(x_n)<1$, it is sufficient that $S_{n+1}(x_n)<2\cdot e^{-x_n/n}$.

Now I state, for later proof:
$$ 0<S_{n+1}(x)-S_{n}(x)<\frac{1}{x+1}\tag{2}.$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get:
$$S_n(x)< -1+(1+1/n)^x\cdot\left(\frac{1}{x+1}+S_n(x)\right),$$
$$\frac{S_n(x)}{S_n(x)+\frac{1}{x+1}}<-1+(1+1/n)^x<e^{x/n}-1,$$

> $$S_n(x) < \frac{e^{x/n}-1}{(2-e^{x/n})(x+1)}.\tag{3}$$

Now it is clear that if $x$ is about $n\log 2$ (how much far can be determined by solving $RHS=1$, i.e. $e^{x/n}=\frac{2x+3}{x+2}$, or $x=n\cdot\log\left(2-\frac{1}{x+2}\right)$, through Newton's method, for instance) the $RHS$ is less than $1$ and we are done:

> $$ S_n\left(n\cdot \log\left(2-\frac{1}{n\log 2}\right)\right)<1\tag{4}$$

is a straightforward consequence of $(3)$; moreover, it goes a little beyond the $n\cdot\log 2$-wall. Now proving that we cannot hope to have $S_n(x)<1$ for an $x$ well below $n\cdot\log 2$ is just an exercise in inequalities-reversing: we just need a $\frac{C}{x+1}$ lower bound for $S_{n+1}(x)-S_{n}(x)$ to replace the LHS of $(2)$ (maybe through the Newton-Cotes formulas with a quantitative error term?). Moreover, we already know that $S_n(x)<1$ implies $x>\frac{2n}{3}-1$ by a straighforward Riemann-sums&convexity argument shown by @127.0.9.6: just a tiny piece of work is still needed.

Answer (score 4):

I was having some luck by defining
$$ S_n(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^x. $$

In the very least, you get a reasonable justification for the $\log{2}$ coefficient. With minimal algebra, one sees
$$ S_n(x) = \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^x \left[1+S_{n-1}(x)\right]. $$

Define $x_n$ such that $S_n(x_n)=1$. We write $x_{n}=x_{n-1}+\Delta_n$. So,
$$ S_n(x_n) = 1 = \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{x_n}\left[1+S_{n-1}(x_{n-1}+\Delta_n)\right] = \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{x_n}\left[2+\Delta_nS_{n-1}'(x_{n-1}) + O(\Delta_n^2)\right]. $$

The part I don't like now is neglecting everything, but suppose the derivatives of $S_{n-1}$ are small at $x_{n-1}$. In which case,
$$ x_n \approx \frac{\log{2}}{\log(n/(n-1))} = \frac{(n-1)\log{2}}{1+O(1/(n-1))} \approx (n-1)\log{2}. $$

However, this might motivate a perturbation solution $x_n-x_{n-1} = \log{2}+O(\epsilon)$ or a limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} (x_n-x_{n-1}) = \log{2}$.

So, not a full solution, but I think a possible, worthwhile line of argument to pursue.

Comment: It may be useful to notice that if $S_n(x_n)=1$, then $$S_n'(x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\log(i/n)\cdot\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^{x_n}$$ can be regarded as a weighted sum of logarithms, that by Jensen's inequality is less than $-\log 2$.

Comment: Unluckyly, this seems to indicate that the derivative of $S_n(x)$ in the point where $S_n(x)=1$ is quite big, in absolute value.

Comment: Moreover, following the main conjecture here we have that $\Delta_n$ is about $\log 2$, so by writing $O(\Delta^2)$ we just hide a constant term under the carpet.